# How do you flatten an array of values into rows in a CosmosDB query?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Given the following collection data in a CosmosDB database:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Blog post #1",
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Blog post #2",
        "tags": ["tag1"]
    }
]
```

How would you flatten this into a result set that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Blog post #1",
        "tagName": "tag1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Blog post #1",
        "tagName": "tag2"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Blog post #1",
        "tagName": "tag3"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Blog post #2",
        "tagName": "tag1"
    }
]
```

The ultimate goal in this example is finding the tag count, so this query would be wrapped in something like SELECT COUNT(1) as count, s.tagName FROM (subquery) s GROUP BY s.tagName.

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Something like this: SELECT c.id, c.Tags FROM c JOIN c.Tags t - this query joins the Tags object in its entirety. What I need is to somehow join the individual values in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the right idea but are using the wrong type of join. You need to use `JOIN IN` to flatten the array.

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, t AS tagName
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.tags
```